# Parse host from url without subdomains etc

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome-extension that reads the domain from `window.location.hostname`. Now for this extension to work properly, I need to be able to separate subdomains and other url variation to the same host. example:

I need all of the following url:s

```
www.google.com
accounts.google.com
photos.google.se
example.google.co.uk
https://google.com
```

all of these need to be resolved to, in this case, "google", in a way that is reliable and will work for any website with sometimes quirky subdomainconfigurations.

this is my current aproach, somewhat simplified:

```
var url = window.location.hostname.split(".") //returns an array of strings
for(i=0;i<url.length;i++){
if(url[i].match(domainregex) //regex for identifying domains ".com",".se",".co.uk" etc
return url[i-1]  //usually what I'm after is directly before the domain, thus i-1
}
```

This approach is alot of hassle, and has proven unreliable at times...Is there any more straitforward way of doing this?

Comment: You could also make use of some existing tools out there. This one seems to work fine: https://github.com/websanova/js-url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more reliable solution to strip the top level domain part and get the main domain part is to use [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat) which is used by Firefox and Chrome and other browsers.

[Several js parsers](https://publicsuffix.org/learn/) of the list data are available if you don't want to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it for my fork of edit-my-cookies, so It will able to change profile of cookies per site. (https://github.com/AminaG/swap-my-cookies-multisite/blob/master/js/tools.js)

It is what I did, and it is working for me. I am sure if it not complete solution, but I am sure it can helps.

```
var remove_sub_domain=function(v){
    var is_co=v.match(/\.co\./)
    v=v.split('.')
    v=v.slice(is_co ? -3: -2)
    v=v.join('.')
    console.log(v)
    return v
}
```

it is working for:

```
www.google.com
accounts.google.com
photos.google.se
example.google.co.uk
google.com
```

if you want it to work also for:

```
http://gooogle.com
```

You first need to remove the protocol:

```
parser=document.createElement('a');
parser.href=url;
host=parser.host;
newurl=remove_sub_domain(host);
```